# Combined entry column Journaltitle/Booktitle in JabRef

Tags: bibliographies, columns, jabref

In the JabRef entry table, I’d like to have a column that displays the `journaltitle` for an `@article` entry and the `booktitle` for an `@incollection` (etc.) entry, rather than having a separate column for `journaltitle` and `booktitle`. They’re never both filled out in one entry, so I could save some column space here.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the columns, go to Options⇒Preferences⇒Entry table columns. In the table, simply enter both field names separated by a slash, so e.g. `journaltitle/booktitle`. You can even combine more than two fields this way. The first non-empty field will be displayed in the entry table.

This feature was implemented following feature request [#438 author/editor column](https://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/feature-requests/438/), but doesn’t seem to be documented elsewhere.

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]